# Division of vectors

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

In R:

```
aff<-c(4,8,12)    
bff<-c(2,4,6)    
aff/bff [1] 2 2 2
```

But vectors' division is undefined.

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In a mathematical sense vector division is undefined, but R and other languages implement element-wise division so if $a = (a_1, a_2)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2)$ then $a / b := (a_1 / b_1, a_2/b_2)$. They implement exactly the same with vector multiplication (and you would have to use %*% to get the dot product). So in your case

$(4,8,12) / (2,4,6) = (4/2, 8/4,12/6)$

Answer (score 1):

The example actually shows how vector division is defined in R. If you use `/` for division, you get element-by-element result. When it makes sense and when it does not depends on the intended use of this operation.